# Adding 2 linked EntityFramework objects doesn't link

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship

I have two entities in my EntityFramework 6.1.1 model that are linked by a foreign key in the backing SQL database. I have a Location entity which contains address details and I have a Client entity which contains name details and a nullable foreign key ID for a Location.

I'm building my first MVC site but have utilised EntityFramework for over 6 years and have been building Microsoft systems for over 10 years. The behaviour below makes no sense to me...

The following code in my Create method SHOULD work:

```
Location location = new Location { LocationID = cvm.Location.LocationID, LocationTypeID = cvm.Location.LocationTypeID, LocationData = string.Empty };
db.Locations.Add(location);
Client client = new Client { ClientID = cvm.ClientID, ClientTypeID = cvm.ClientTypeID, Email = cvm.Email, PhoneNumber = cvm.PhoneNumber, ESign = cvm.ESign, ClientData = string.Empty };
db.Clients.Add(client);
client.Location = location;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Unfortunately the result after the SaveChanges is called is that both of the entities are inserted into their respective database tables BUT the foreign key in the Client table is null! I've tried manually setting the LocationID property in the Client entity but it makes no change. I've tried saving the Location entity BEFORE adding the Client entity but it makes no change. The ONLY way I can get the link to work is with the following code:

```
Location location = new Location { LocationID = cvm.Location.LocationID, LocationTypeID = cvm.Location.LocationTypeID, LocationData = string.Empty };
db.Locations.Add(location);
Client client = new Client { ClientID = cvm.ClientID, ClientTypeID = cvm.ClientTypeID, Email = cvm.Email, PhoneNumber = cvm.PhoneNumber, ESign = cvm.ESign, ClientData = string.Empty };
db.Clients.Add(client);
db.SaveChanges();
client.Location = location;
db.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

The most frustrating part is that I have another entity (Property) which also has a foreign key link to the Location entity. In the Property table however the LocationID foreign key is NOT nullable, and the (equivalent) first code DOES work.

Has anyone else run into this issue and can explain why the first code isn't working? Is it possible this is an EF6.1.1 bug?

Comment: So for reference the failure was mine in that I had failed to update an insert trigger to correctly set the LocationID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to explicitly save the child(location)

```
Location location = new Location { LocationID = cvm.Location.LocationID, LocationTypeID = cvm.Location.LocationTypeID, LocationData = string.Empty };
Client client = new Client { ClientID = cvm.ClientID, ClientTypeID = cvm.ClientTypeID, Email = cvm.Email, PhoneNumber = cvm.PhoneNumber, ESign = cvm.ESign, ClientData = string.Empty };
client.Location = location;
db.Clients.Add(client);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: That certainly seems to be the case, however I get the same result from your code as in the OP being that the client is saved and the location is saved but the locationid foreign key isn't set for the client...

Comment: Is this code first or model first? If code first, how are you setting up the relationship? What does the generated SQL look like? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx

Comment: Model first. I'm a bit old school like that (plus the database has evolved over 10+ years). I'll definitely look into the db logging and update once I have more info.

Comment: That DELIGHTFUL facepalm moment where you realise that you failed to update the OnInsert trigger in your database to properly insert the foreign key... :( Time to go update the 'modifying database tables' procedure... *Check Insert Trigger!

Comment: Should have said InsteadOfInsert above